# see if date is in date range

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

If I do this:

```
date1 = "2012-01-01".to_date
@dates = (Date.today..Date.today + 60.days)
```

How can I check if date1 is within @dates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.include?`:

```
@dates.include?(date1)
```

Or in Ruby 1.9, you can also use `.cover?`:

```
@dates.cover?(date1)
```

Comment: I was just doing this, and it wouldn't work... I bet I was forgetting the ?  Thanks for the solution.